# To find the Taylor Series expansion about origin of $f(x)=\int_0^x \tan^{-1}t dt$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

To find the Taylor Series expansion about origin of

> $f(x)=\int_0^x \tan^{-1}t dt$

I have used $\tan^{-1}t=t-t^3/3+t^5/5-t^7/7+....$ and simply integrating I found f(x)= $\sum(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}/(2n(2n-1))$ though I know the standard way to do is finding $f',f'',f'''$ and so on and their corresponding value in $0$ then using $f(x)=\sum (f^n(x)/n!) x^n$. Is the approach correct?
Also using this result I have to find the sum of the series

> $1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}+......$

I am not understanding how to do it? Any hint?

Comment: $1/2n(2n-1)=1/(2n-1)-1/2n$ maybe...

Comment: Was my approach correct to find the expansion?

Comment: yup i understand. it is $\int_0^{1}tan^{-1}tdt$ then by parts gives the answer.

Comment: what about my first question?

Comment: I wanted to know the approach to find the series correct?@ Yves Daoust

Comment: I amnot getting...

Comment: Please post an answer @ Yves Daoust

Comment: The standard method IMO is do what you did in the event we can.  If we can't, we resort to Taylor's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Rewrite this sum as
$$\Bigl(1-\frac13+\frac15-\dotsm\Bigr)-\Bigl(\frac12-\frac14+\frac16-\dotsm\Bigr).$$